# Need to modify ls command in xv6

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

This is the code of ls command in XV6 os. i want to modify it in a way such that when i run ls command the line numbers are also displayed with each output. When i tried to modify the ls command i wasn't getting the number with each line but getting total number of outputs separately. The function of the ls command could be found under the name of void ls.

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"
#include "fs.h"

char*
fmtname(char *path)
{
  static char buf[DIRSIZ+1];
  char *p;

  // Find first character after last slash.
  for(p=path+strlen(path); p >= path && *p != '/'; p--)
    ;
  p++;

  // Return blank-padded name.
  if(strlen(p) >= DIRSIZ)
    return p;
  memmove(buf, p, strlen(p));
  memset(buf+strlen(p), ' ', DIRSIZ-strlen(p));
  return buf;
}

void
ls(char *path)
{
  char buf[512], *p;
  int fd;
  struct dirent de;
  struct stat st;

  if((fd = open(path, 0)) < 0){
    printf(2, "ls: cannot open %s\n", path);
    return;
  }

  if(fstat(fd, &st) < 0){
    printf(2, "ls: cannot stat %s\n", path);
    close(fd);
    return;
  }

  switch(st.type){
  case T_FILE:
    printf(1, "%s %d %d %d\n", fmtname(path), st.type, st.ino, st.size);
    break;

  case T_DIR:
    if(strlen(path) + 1 + DIRSIZ + 1 > sizeof buf){
      printf(1, "ls: path too long\n");
      break;
    }
    strcpy(buf, path);
    p = buf+strlen(buf);
    *p++ = '/';
    while(read(fd, &de, sizeof(de)) == sizeof(de)){
      if(de.inum == 0)
        continue;
      memmove(p, de.name, DIRSIZ);
      p[DIRSIZ] = 0;
      if(stat(buf, &st) < 0){
        printf(1, "ls: cannot stat %s\n", buf);
        continue;
      }
      printf(1, "%s %d %d %d\n", fmtname(buf), st.type, st.ino, st.size);
    }
    break;
  }
  close(fd);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;

  if(argc < 2){
    ls(".");
    exit();
  }
  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    ls(argv[i]);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: What output? That function only prints error messages.

Comment: Where is the rest of the function?

Comment: I have edited the code to include the whole code, kindly review it

Comment: @AbdullahKhan What you want is unclear. Can you post an example of what you want (constructed by hand) and what you get?

Comment: Usually when we run ls command in linux, the file names in that directory are displayed but what i want is to modify the ls command code in such a way that when i run the command, not only the file names are displayed but also the line number along them e.g there should be 1 with file1, 2 with file2 and so on

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I see, but with the code you posted, what is the result you got? ("It doesn't work" is not an acceptable answer)

Comment: In Linux, one would use either `scandir()` or `nftw()`, and `lstat()` when details like date, mode, owner etc. are printed.  In BSDs, possibly `fts()` and `lstat()`.  In Windows, you might have to use `opendir()`/`readdir()`/`closedir()`, which are technically part of standard C, but much, much inferior to the POSIX and BSD interfaces.  None of these are provided by xv6 at all.  The code shown is simply wrong on any system other than xv6, so marking it [tag:linux] is simply incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan. The code you post is exactly this one https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/7894fcd21732dd2ddfbb9beca52d037a62ed11f4/ls.c. Where are *your* modifications?